# How do I add 'Like Page' button to my URL timeline post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have used opengraph to share my website to facebook. Is there any way I can add a 'Like Page' button to it, so that my associated FB business page gets liked instead of the shared post?

[image]

Comment: Have you read through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button?

Comment: @Zach Sadler: Did you read my question?

Comment: I did and I'm not sure I can help. Facebook generates the resulted shared posts themselves, and I don't think you can add a button to like your business to the post they generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

> “`article:publisher` - This property links to the publisher of the article. The target of this property must be a Facebook Page. When displayed in the News Feed, Facebook may offer the ability to like the publisher. Note that this tag is only available to media publishers.”

So your `og:type` of the shared object must be `article`, and your page that you specify as publisher must be in the appropriate category.

Notice also how it says there that Facebook *“may offer”* the page like button, meaning there is no guarantee it will show up if Facebook doesn’t think your page is important enough.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a sponsored post. The add searches what friend liked that page and suggests you to like that page, because your friends liked it.